# I want to use kubernetes API to restart the deployment from the AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-lambda, kubernetes-ingress

I have a eks cluster where I have a pod A and I want to deploy a new pod B that is dedicated to be used to restart the deployment of pod A via kubernetes api such that I call an LB service of POD B from lambda in such form it will restart the deployment of pod A ,just looking forward on how  we can achieve that ,It would be really great if anyone can assist on this.

An Approach on how to restart the pod from another pod using kubernetes API

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the client library and use it for restarting the POD.

List of K8s library : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/

If you use **python** :

```
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
import json
import requests
import time
logger = logging.getLogger('k8s_events')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# If running inside pod
#config.load_incluster_config()

# If running locally
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
v1ext = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api()
```

way to authenticate the with K8s cluster, you can also use the service account to authenticate and further add the method to restart the POD.

If your cluster is exposed or proxy there you can also patch deployment so which will also auto restart the deployment(POD).

```
curl -k --data '{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubrnetes.io/restartedAt":"'"$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z)"'"}}}}}' -XPATCH   -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" localhost:8001/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/<name of deployment>
```

**Extra** :

If you don't want to run **API** you can also run the **kubectl** command on the cluster and restat the POD A from POD B.

Ref : https://itnext.io/running-kubectl-commands-from-within-a-pod-b303e8176088